# PHP: How can you remove/replace a specific href attribute value

Tags: php, javascript, performance, api, replace

I am parsing some articles from a database with php and in the articles there are links which I would like to overwrite. Link always start with "`http://cdn.example.com/`" and the end parser is `htmlspecialchars_decode($item->parse_articles(), ENT_NOQUOTES)`.

So before the articles are passed to the HTML DOM, I would like to **replace** all those href's that contain (?) example.com or maybe even if faster and possible to remove the `<a>` completely.

`<a href="http://cdn.example.com/whatever?else" target="_blank"></a>`.

**How is this possible**? and if possible, **is this considered faster option** than passing it first to the DOM and manipulating it from there on the client-side?

Comment: as for speed, shouldn't make a big difference, unless there is a huge amount of text. You will likely need a custom regex of some sort to detect the matching href tags. `preg_match()` or `preg_replace()` will do the trick. Id say if youre comfortable doing so in JS then go that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like the following in PHP:

```
$newtext = preg_replace('/^("http:\/\/cdn\.example\.com\/){1}(.*)("){1}$/', '"#" class="disabled-link"', $oldtext);
```

$oldtext being your input article as a string.
$newtext being the text to echo on the page.

Broken down:

1. Find text starting with "http://cdn.example.com/
2. Then match anything
3. Stop at "
4. Replace with "#" class="disabled-link"

This should let you remove the link and also I added the class part so that you can add some CSS to style the links as text.

Example:

```
.disabled-link{
    color:#000;
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: default;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

All this combined will provide users with a link that is completely invisible without looking into the DOM or the source.